# alert message in Multilingual website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, javascript

i am using resource files for showing html content(like label names ) in my multilingual website.The resource files are different for different countries.The website is built on Asp.Net MVC3.

I am showing a javascript alert whose message is picked from a resource file as shown below:
alert('@Resources.Areas.Admin.Views.Program.Local.Create.msgDate3');
Now in the resource file for msgDate3 i have text in french as "La fecha de inicio deberá ser menor que la fecha de término" 
This alert on the website gets displayed as "La fecha de inicio deberá ser menor que la fecha de término" where the "á" and "é" are not getting displayed properly.
How to display these special charcters?

I also have data in other languages where similar issue comes up with these characters.How to display them?

EDIT:-

(In my app english resource files are named as "cshtmlfilename.resx" e.g. create.resx and other culture resource files are named as "cshtmlfilename.culturename.resx" e.g. create.es-MX.resx)

I found out that the javascript code of my page breaks on the alerts that i have placed in the page in the format`alert('@Html.Raw(Resources.Areas.Admin.Views.Program.Local.Create.msgDate2)');`
where 'Create.msgDate2' refers to the resource file Create.resx's key msgDate2.
The break msg in firebug comes up as `

> unterminated string literal
>   [Break On This Error] alert('ควรจะลงวันที่ที่เริ่มก่อนวันสุดท้ายของการสิ้นสุด 
>   (this is the msg i get for thailand (th-th) 
>   when i am modifying the translation for msgDate2 then the script is working fine.I am sure some issue is happenning with the characters of this language which are making the javascript to stop.
>   Any solutions for this??

Answer (score 1):

Use Html.Raw to avoid string encoding:

```
alert('@Html.Raw(Resources.Areas.Admin.Views.Program.Local.Create.msgDate3)');
```

Htmlhelpers like Html.LabelFor(..) return an IHtmlString which aren't encoded like regular strings in the view, so that's why you don't have issues with labels.

Comment: IT worked fine for some cultures but did not for some like thailand (th-th),Latvia (lv-lv).

Answer (score 0):

What browser(s) is this happening in? Can you please post the Head element of your HTML file. I think you could be missing a meta tag for encoding. Try adding the following to the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```